# jQuery using arrow key scrolling during presentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a presentation using HTML for a project I'm working on. The presentation will be full-page slides and I want to implement a script with jQuery so that when the arrow keys are pressed, it scrolls smoothly between slides. Left being previous slide and right being next slide obviously.

I wrote a script but it only works the first time. I'm very new to jQuery and I can't seem to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
   $('.slide').prev().ScrollTo({
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
}
if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
   $('.slide').next().ScrollTo({
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: One problem, if you look at your Javascript console, is that `.previous` is not a function. You want `.prev`

Comment: @bytesized Thank you! The function still only works for the first two slides though :(

Comment: @user3894056 see i created one fiddle may be it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/0tue685a/

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    // console.log($('[class ^=slide]'))

    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        if ($('#container').find('.scroll').prev()[0]) {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($('#container').find('.scroll').prev()[0]).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            console.log($($('#container').find('.scroll').prev()[0]).addClass('scroll'))
            console.log($($('#container').find('.scroll')[1]).removeClass('scroll'))
        } else {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($('#container').children()[$('#container').children().length - 1]).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            $($('#container').children()[$('#container').children().length - 1]).addClass('scroll')
            $($('#container').find('.scroll')[0]).removeClass('scroll')


        }



    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        if ($('#container').find('.scroll').next()[0]) {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($('#container').find('.scroll').next()[0]).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            $($('#container').find('.scroll').next()[0]).addClass('scroll')
            $($('#container').find('.scroll')[0]).removeClass('scroll')
        } else {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($('#container').children()[0]).offset().top
            }, 1000);

            $($('#container').children()[0]).addClass('scroll')
            console.log($($('#container').children()[0]))
            $($('#container').find('.scroll')[1]).removeClass('scroll')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works for scrolling to the next slide, but sliding to the previous slide only works once.

Comment: @user3894056 if you can see it is working but if your on first element i.e red one then prev not work if you want then will do that also

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, now if you refresh the page while on the second slide or so it refreshes and loads on that page. How do I make it so it will always load with the first slide on screen?

Comment: @user3894056 you can create one function like firstLoad or something and call it on  load in example i crated goToTop button so on click of that black button it will scroll to first element so in your case you can call this function directly on load http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/0tue685a/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `$('.slide')` does not select the slide you are on, it selects ALL the slides that match the selector. You could try something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_slide = $('.slide').first();
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
   current_slide = current_slide.prev();
   current_slide.ScrollTo({
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
}
if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
   current_slide = current_slide.next();
   current_slide.ScrollTo({
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @user3894056 I think I fixed it. It is difficult for me to test, because I am having trouble duplicating your setup.